# Why is the the temperature change due to the combustion of paraffin wax so high (10000 Kelvin)?

Tags: thermodynamics, enthalpy, combustion, hydrocarbons, wax

I'm trying to work out the temperature change (I got something like 10k Kelvin,hotter than the Sun's core...) caused by the combustion of paraffin wax which has a  molar enthalpy of combustion $E^{wax}_{m}=15MJmol^{-1}$.
$$38O_2+C_{25}H_{52} \to 25CO_2 +26 H_2O \tag{1}$$
so for a given number of moles of oxygen $n_{O_2}$, the reaction requires $(1/38)n_{O_2} $ moles of wax ($C_{25}H_{52}$) and produces $(25/38)n_{O_2}$ moles of $CO_2$ and $(26/38)n_{O_2}$ moles of $H_2O$.

Consider a thermal-dynamically isolated system composed of 1 Litre of pure $O_2$ under STP (plus the required amount of $C_{25}H_{25}$ for complete combustion). Calculate the temperature change due to the combustion. The molar heat capacity of $CO_2$ and $H_2O$ are both approximately $30Jmol^{-1}K^{-1}$

From $Q=mc\Delta T$:
$$n_{wax}E_m^{wax}=n_{CO_2}c_{m,CO_2}\Delta T+n_{water}c_{m,water}\Delta T $$
$$ \left(\frac{1}{38}n_{O_2} \right)E_m^{wax}=\left(\frac{25}{38}n_{O_2} \right)c_{m,CO_2}\Delta T+\left (\frac{26}{38}n_{O_2} \right)c_{m,H_2O}\Delta T$$

$$\Delta T=\frac{(1/38)E_m^{wax}}{((25/38)c_{m,CO_2}+(26/38)c_{m,H_2O}}$$
$$\Delta T=\frac{E_m^{wax}}{25c_{m,CO_2}+26c_{m,H_2O}}=\frac{15MJmol^{-1}}{(25+26)\times 30Jmol^{-1}K^{-1}} \approx 10000 K$$

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Heat capacity does not really stay constant at temperatures that high. Also, much of the heat is irradiated outside or passed to the surroundings. If we neglect both these effects (even though they are not really negligible), then that's what we would have.

Comment: @Ivan Neretin
 Thanks.  So my working is not wrong then I guess? Another thing that intrigued me was that $\Delta T $ is independent of the number of moles of $O_2$ initially present?

Comment: Looks right to me. As for the moles of O2, there are (presumably) exactly as much as needed for the full combustion. Take more O2, and you'll have an excess of it; take less, and you'll have an excess of paraffin. Both would appear in the denominator and thus change the ΔT.

Comment: Cross posted: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/673720/313612.

Comment: As a curiosity exercise try to paper-see what thermometer (range) you would need using a calorimeter taking some data from your exercise or the Web in addition to those you already have. Perhaps it would look less spectacular.